# jQuery hide/show functions overwrite html inline style background image?

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

My hide()/show() functions overwrite inline style background-image with display: none/block, but somehow it doesn't overwrite the first (.concrete) .img background-image HTML element.

By default the .concrete has display: block in CSS and the other .img have display: none;

HTML:

```
<p class="slider-link concrete active"><?php the_field("product1"); ?></p>
<p class="slider-link light"><?php the_field("product2"); ?></p>

<div class="img concrete" style="background-image: url(<?php the_field('concrete_img'); ?>)">
    <div class="content">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
<div class="img light" style="background-image: url(<?php the_field('light_img'); ?>)">
    <div class="content">
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.slider-link').click(function() {
    $('.slider-link').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    if ($(this).hasClass('concrete')) {
        $('.img').hide();
        $('.img.concrete').show();
    } else if ($(this).hasClass('light')) {
        $('.img').hide();
        $('.img.light').show(); 
    });
```

Comment: I doubt that show/hide actually overwrites the inline style for a background-image. Your problem must be something else, but with the given problem description and code, it is hard to tell what that could be. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: you need to set backgroumd image in jquery. not inline style.

Answer (score 0):

My bad! The ACF image fields return image objects (by default) but the first one i made before i had changed to return "image url" so it would work with the inline background-image style. And because they had false syntax it just overwrote the bad lines when inspecting with DevTools.